# DFS - disable folder target stops replication or not?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs-r

need quick help. We have recreated the DFS namespace with two targets and replication group but there is a lot of data to replicate and dfsrdiag ReplicationState still shows updates. Seems like the folder target from the second server should be disabled until the replication is complete is that right?
I am not not sure if I can do DFS management / namespaces / ... / disable folder target safely if it will not interfere with the replication. Or is this independent? Looks to me like it is. Please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer on MS technet:
The DFS Namespace and DFS Replication can run independently of each other, so in your case the DFS Replication should not stop.

DFS Namespace
Virtualizes the file shares so that multiple servers with the same files can be tasked with sharing the files.

DFS Replication
Handles the synchronization of multiple file systems.

I did it - disabled one target in namespaces and yes the replication continues. Confirmed